# an attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions calling Azure IMDS

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

I am having trouble calling the Azure Instance Metadata Service (IMDS) from an App Service to get a token.  We have an App Service that was created >18 months ago.  Recently we enabled `Managed Identity` for it.  On the azure portal page there is a [great link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) that describes MI and how to use it.

However when I try to make a REST call to `http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token` using the documented parameters I always get an exception `an attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.`  Is there some local configuration we need to enable so this endpoint works?  Is this something that won't work because this App Service was created so long ago?

I can use the `MSI VM Extension` and get a token successfully but the doc mentions this API was supposed to be deprecated in January of 2019.  I can also use the `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` library successfully and get a valid token.

I would prefer to make a simple REST call since that is how we communicate with our other dependent services.  Sample snippets are below.

Can someone help me understand the best choice here?

MSI VM Extension (works but is documented as deprecated)

```
var endpoint = environment.MSI_ENDPOINT;
uri = new Uri($"{endpoint}?api-version=2017-09-01&resource=https://{audience}");
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
req.Headers.Add("Secret", environment.MSI_SECRET); 
var resp = await client.SendAsync(req);
var text = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Using the TokenProvider nuget (works but adds another nuget to the code)

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
token = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync($"https://{audience}/");
```

Calling Azure IMDS (throws `an attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.`  )

```
uri = new Uri($"http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://{audience}");
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
req.Headers.Add("Metadata", "true"); // api requirement
var resp = await client.SendAsync(req);
var text = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

The [link you provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) could be more clear about this, but the IMDS is only present on and specific to Azure VMs.

To get an access token from an App Service, you use the MSI_ENDPOINT and MSI_SECRET environment variables. This is how both of the first two options you gave work (see the [implementation in AppAuth library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/mgmtcommon/AppAuthentication/Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/TokenProviders/MsiAccessTokenProvider.cs)). Both examples are also using the same REST calls/API version, which means using either of these options would be functionally equivalent. So when choosing between these two options, it comes down your preference. :)

The AzureServiceTokenProvider in the AppAuth library/Nuget does provide a layer of abstraction from the token retrieval logic though, as well as a built-in token cache, and a simplified authentication experience between local development and prod/test deployments. You can read more about the AppAuth library and its benefits [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication).

Comment: The link I provided is from the Azure Portal when I view the Identity settings for my App Service.  That's a fairly handy place to have a link like that so maybe the portal folks can take either "create an App Service-specific link" bug or a doc clarification bug.  Reading about the `TokenProvider` it seems like that could be useful for making the service `just work` regardless of where it's deployed.

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for this info! I can definitely see how this can lead to confusion, I will see if I can find the right contacts to update the documentation and make things a bit more clear.