Can We Use SPN identity for creating MSAL token? in C# Don't want use Token
I  have tried to create MSAL token for my demon application.
I have tried blow code
IManagedIdentityApplication mi = ManagedIdentityApplicationBuilder.Create(ManagedIdentityId.WithUserAssignedClientId("myspnid"))
.Build();

              AuthenticationResult result = await mi.AcquireTokenForManagedIdentity("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default")
                  .ExecuteAsync()
                  .ConfigureAwait(false);
              _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request."+ result.AccessToken);
              return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions! token" + result.AccessToken);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions! error"+ex.Message);
              _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request." +ex.Message);

          }

I don't want to use secrets.
Cos I already have created app I have SPN service principle ID.
can any one have idea on this?
I m adding more details for more clarity

I m using this client id  and added full permission
for  for graph
Error is
"No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId."

What error are you getting?

was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

ttps://graph.microsoft.com/User.Readi changed this

attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992713/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi

The error usually occurs if firewall is blocking the port 443 or the IP.

no issue with fire wall but the question is
Can We Use SPN identity for creating MSAL token?

Yes we can use  SPN identity for creating MSAL token

can you share me code snippet?

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227249/how-to-connect-azure-log-analytic-workspace-using-managed-identity-from-net-api/77227828#77227828

To use SPN identity for creating MSAL token/Access token, check the below:
For sample, I used the below PowerShell script to assign permissions to the managed identity:
Connect-AzureAD

$TenantID="TenantID"
$GraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" 
$NameOfMSI="ruktestMI"
$PermissionName = "User.Read.All"

$MSI = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$NameOfMSI'")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
$GraphServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$GraphAppId'"
$AppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | 
Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $PermissionName -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains "Application"}

New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $MSI.ObjectId -PrincipalId $MSI.ObjectId -ResourceId $GraphServicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $AppRole.Id



Now to generate token, you can make use of below code as a workaround:
using System;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Core;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "XXXX"; // The Client ID of the user assigned identity

        AccessToken token = await new DefaultAzureCredential(
            new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId
            })
            .GetTokenAsync(
                new TokenRequestContext(
                    new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }
                ));

        Console.WriteLine(token.Token);
    }
}


By using the above access token, you can call Microsoft Graph API
Note that: Either make use of Managed identity or interactive flow ( without passing the client secret). OR make use of ROPC flow which is non interactive and doesnt need client Secret to generate token. Using SPN identity and without client secret and non interactively it is not possible to generate token.
Reference:
Options for obtaining an access token with Azure application to application authentication by Anoop

AccessToken token = await new DefaultAzureCredential(
new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId
})
here the client id is Service principle id?

Yes It is the client of SPN

Did it work for you by passing client ID of SPN?

"No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId."

i added images in question self if you can check

You created Azure AD application not Managed identity

You need to create managed identity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-manage-user-assigned-managed-identities?pivots=identity-mi-methods-azp and pass its ClientID

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

still checking some option there is no direct solution for this so i m checking and will update for community

Azure managed identity and Service principal are different. https://www.atmosera.com/blog/azure-service-principal-vs-managed-identity/ Hence you cannot use Service principal ID only to generate token

yes as we discussed in chat also we will no be able to use spn directly
